# Error on trying to create my first space: Host not enough

Tags: nebula-graph

Going through the kick start i have the DB running as a docker extension and have logged in.

https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.5.0/2.quick-start/1.quick-start-workflow/

`CREATE SPACE bverse(partition_num=10, replica_factor=1, vid_type=fixed_string(30));`

gives the error. tried reducing partitions, no luck

digging around i found something about setting up hosts

`ADD HOSTS 192.168.10.100:9779, 192.168.10.101:9779, 192.168.10.102:9779;`

which runs OK...

but `CREATE SPACE` still fails.

Is there a getting started that actually works? this isn't very reassuring.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to put you in this situation.

For the fresh installation, if we go with NebulaGraph Docker-compose or Docker extension, they should get ready just after the cluster is up, the underlying `ADD HOSTS` will be taken care of already.

- `ADD HOSTS` refers to activate storaged hosts
- `SHOW HOSTS` will show the status of activated HOSTS, In case they are offline, we should look into their logs(failed to boot, network issue in communication etc..)

I hope you ended up getting the cluster up.

If not, please kindly share the storaged/metad log so I can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have started NebulaGraph with the Docker desktop extension, there are more steps to getting started:

1. Login > 2. Activate StorageD > 3. Load Dataset > 4. Query > 5. Finish

The error message you face means you haven't gone through Step 2 properly.
This is a one-time setup step on first-time usage.
Go to the Nebula console and run

```
ADD HOSTS "storaged0":9779,"storaged1":9779,"storaged2":9779
```